# Capture more then one photo and send to the server UWP C#

Tags: c#, camera, windows-10, uwp

I should make a simple service, that allows making some photos and sending them to the server. But I have some problems with it, I'm using the code below:

```
public async void PhotoCap()
    {
        CameraCaptureUI cc = new CameraCaptureUI();

        cc.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
        cc.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(3, 4);
        cc.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;
        StorageFile sf = await cc.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
        if (sf != null)
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            IRandomAccessStream rs = await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            bmp.SetSource(rs); //add photo to the ImageView
            image.Source = bmp;
        }
    }
```

But how can I capture more than one photo and send them to the server? Should I make a loop for it?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I capture more than one photo and send them to the server? Should I make a loop for it?

I think what you need is [VariablePhotoSequenceCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn652564).

For details about using  `VariablePhotoSequenceCapture`, please refer to official documentation: [Variable photo sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/variable-photo-sequence).

For Uploading Images, you can use [BackgroundTransfer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207242). And **Uploading multiple files** section of [Background Transfer's Official Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/networking/background-transfers) explains how to upload multiple files. And there is also an [Official Sample of BackgroundTransfer](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer) that you can refer to.